# Processing XPath queries that don't include XML namespaces?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, namespaces

Users are inputting quite complex `XPath`s to query the database.
They will only use one fixed namespace for the queries. Currently users have to enter expressions like:

```
//ns:tag1/ns:tag2 | //ns:tag3/ns:*[not(ns:tag2)]
```

But this syntax gets overly complicated very quickly, and takes longer to enter. Also it is quite error prone, for users who aren't overly familiar with xpath. Users would ideally input the `XPath` without namespaces --

```
//tag1/tag2 | //tag3/*[not(tag2)]
```

So much easier for them! But not for me. How can I deal with this kind of expression? I do know the namespace that needs to be inserted. Is there any way to automatically insert the `ns` in the appropriate places in the Xpath expression? I am using Python `lxml`. Or can I set a default namespace?

Note that `*[local-name() = 'entry']` is not possible here!

### edit

In python I am calling

```
currentNode.xpath(query, {'ns':'http://myaddress.com/userns'})
```

where `currentNode` is an `etree.Element`.

Comment: To what function in `lxml` are you passing the users' queries?

Comment: good point, I am sending them to `currentNode.xpath(query, {'ns':'http://myaddress.com/userns'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath 2.0 solves this by allowing you to specify a default namespace which is applied to all unprefixed element names in the query. Unfortunately, XPath 2.0 isn't readily available to Python users.

An alternative is to transform the document before your users query it, so that it doesn't use any namespaces.